# Can't Install psutil Windows 64 bit

Tags: python, windows, pip, psutil

I just installed VS C++ and reinstalled python 3.10, but psutil still wont install and I'm at a bit of a loss

Here is The pastebin for the entire error because I couldn't post the whole thing in this question: https://pastebin.com/jaAti01Z

This is the error message I'm getting:

````
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\blake\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qq5hf6xc\\psutil_24345e83dd374ad78bb9abe254436683\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\blake\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qq5hf6xc\\psutil_24345e83dd374ad78bb9abe254436683\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z6lre3nt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: The error is **fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory** https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+io.h+No+such+file+or+directory